# What is the script font used by our engraving machine?

Tags: font-identification, script

Can someone help me identify this script font?

I've tried using WhatTheFont, Identifont, WhatFontIs, FontSpring and Adobe Font Match. No luck.

The font I'm trying to identify is used for an engraving machine at my place of work. We offer engraving on some of our products and would like to identify the font so I can create a web application to show previews of how the engraving will look on our products.

[image: Isolated letters from picture]

[image: Engraving plates]

Comment: Have you tried asking the manufacturer / supplier of the engraving machine? It may well not be a 'font' as such.

Comment: Looking at it (I've been a "calligrapher" for about 60 years) I, too, would guess it's not a proper font:  it doesn't have enough regularity.  (Compare, for example, the opening swash loops on the two caps, the loop at the center of the K, & the different sizes of the final hook on both caps)